# How do I upload an image to both database and root folder?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to add products to my website and I want to include an image in each product. I have created the folder that the image should go to and created a row in the table for the image. I'm using dreamweaver and I tried to insert record but I get an error (Column 'image' cannot be null) so I kept looking for codes from here and there to solve it and now I don't get errors but all the things I submitted doesn't go to the database, only the image go to the root folder.

The message box doesn't show that the product has been added. I have read that mysqli and mysql can't be mixed, could that be the problem? I'm still a beginner so I hope the question was clear to understand. Thanks.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/MJ_conn.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "1";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "false";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && false) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "Login.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_MJ_conn, $MJ_conn);
$query_AddProduct = "SELECT * FROM products";
$AddProduct = mysql_query($query_AddProduct, $MJ_conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_AddProduct = mysql_fetch_assoc($AddProduct);
$totalRows_AddProduct = mysql_num_rows($AddProduct);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include("db.php"); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Product List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IndexStyle.css"/>
    <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextarea.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationSelect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextarea.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationSelect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<body class="body">
    <header class="MainHeader">
    <img src="images/header-image-5.jpg">
    <nav><ul>
         <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="Product.php">Products</a></li>
         <li><a href="AboutUs.php">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="ContactUs.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="MainBody">
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="insert_product" id="insert_product">
        <table width="800" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="144">Product Name:</td>
                <td width="646"><span id="sprytextfield1">
                  <label for="ProductName"></label>
                  <input type="text" name="product_name" id="ProductName">
                <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Price:</td>
                <td>RM <span id="sprytextfield2">
                  <label for="ProductPrice"></label>
                  <input type="text" name="price" id="ProductPrice">
                <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Category:</td>
                <td><span id="spryselect1">
                  <label for="ProductCategory"></label>
                  <select name="category" id="ProductCategory">
                    <option value="Shirts">Shirts</option>
                    <option value="Pants">Pants</option>
                    <option value="Shoes">Shoes</option>
                  </select>
                <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Product Details:</td>
                <td><span id="sprytextarea1">
                  <label for="ProductDetails"></label>
                  <textarea name="details" id="ProductDetails" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
                <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Product Image:</td>
                <td><label for="ProductImage"></label>
                <input type="file" name="image" id="ProductImage"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_AddProduct['id']; ?>"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="ProductSubmit" id="ProductSubmit" value="Add Product"></td>
              </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
    <aside class="SideBar">
        <p>MySideBar 
        </p>
    </aside>
    <Footer class="Footer"> 
        <p>Copyrights reserved 
        </p>
    </Footer>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1");
var sprytextfield2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield2");
var sprytextarea1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextarea("sprytextarea1");
var spryselect1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationSelect("spryselect1");
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
mysql_free_result($AddProduct);


    if(isset($_POST['ProductSubmit'])){

        //getting the text data from the fields
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $details = $_POST['details'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];

        //getting the image from the field
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"ProductImages/$image");

         $AddProduct = "insert into products (id,product_name,price,details, category, image) values ('$id','$product_name','$price','$details', '$category','$image')";

         $AddProduct = mysqli_query($con, $AddProduct);

         if($AddProduct){

         echo "<script>alert('Product Has been inserted!')</script>";
         echo "<script>window.open('AddProduct.php','_self')</script>";

         }
    }
?>
```

This is the db.php folder:

```
<?php 
                // After uploading to online server, change this connection accordingly

                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mjwebsite");

                if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                  {
                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                  }

                ?>
```

Comment: awful bit of indenting, make your code more legible please.

Comment: Note that there is no need to store an image in DB. You can simply store the image URL instead. This will save you huge size in DB and will be faster and easier to manage. Use only mysqli and not mysql as it is outdated.

Comment: @coderodour I have edited it now, I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi That is what I meant, I just didn't explain it well. So there is nothing with the mysqli statements that I wrote?

Comment: I am not sure, but you may be correct in that that mixing up mysql and mysqli APIs is the issue here. That is not a good practice and will fail you further down SOON if not immediately.

Comment: If only the alert is not showing, rather then `echo "<script>alert('Product Has been inserted!')</script>";`, try to close the PHP by `?>` and then add alert like you normally do in an HTML. Don't forget to open PHP after JS.